# ruby 2次元配列内の計算方法

Tags: ruby

```
arrays=[[7,5],[8,9,9,8],[13,13],[3,4,2,15,18],[3,2],[0,3,6,10,14,7],[7,10,9,11,14],
[4,8,5,8,1,10],[5,11,21,2],[11,18,19,17]]
=>
[12, 34, 26, 42, 5, 40, 51, 36, 39, 65]
```

のような結果にしたいのですが、手順を教えてほしいです。

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローへようこそ！一般に、「計算方法」だけだと何がしたいのか読み取るのが困難ですので、どのような計算がしたいのか具体的に記述してください。今回の質問ではサンプルコードから「2次元配列内の配列の合計を求めて1次元の配列にしたい」という目的（ですよね？）が読み取れて、無事回答が得られましたが、より複雑な内容だと目的がつかめず、回答が得られなくなります。

Answer (score 2):

[`Array#map` メソッド](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-map)を用いて、各配列に対して [`Array#sum` メソッド](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum)を実行すれば良いと思います。

```rb
arrays = [
  [7, 5],
  [8, 9, 9, 8],
  [13, 13],
  [3, 4, 2, 15, 18],
  [3, 2],
  [0, 3, 6, 10, 14, 7],
  [7, 10, 9, 11, 14],
  [4, 8, 5, 8, 1, 10],
  [5, 11, 21, 2],
  [11, 18, 19, 17]
]

p arrays.map(&:sum) #=> [12, 34, 26, 42, 5, 40, 51, 36, 39, 65]
```

もし Ruby 2.4 より古いバージョンを使用している場合は、[`Enumerable#inject` メソッド](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)を用いることができます。

```rb
arrays = [
  [7, 5],
  [8, 9, 9, 8],
  [13, 13],
  [3, 4, 2, 15, 18],
  [3, 2],
  [0, 3, 6, 10, 14, 7],
  [7, 10, 9, 11, 14],
  [4, 8, 5, 8, 1, 10],
  [5, 11, 21, 2],
  [11, 18, 19, 17]
]

p arrays.map { |e| e.inject(:+) } #=> [12, 34, 26, 42, 5, 40, 51, 36, 39, 65]
```

Comment: `sum`メソッドがArrayに入ったのは、Ruby 2.4以降のようです。ちょっと古いRubyが標準装備のシステムもあるので、その辺りも触れておかれた方が良いように思います。